# InvocableMethod - One Input and one output

Tags: invocable-method

Can someone let me know if there is a better way of coding this?

I want to pass one ID to the class from a Visual Flow, which is the ID of the current user, and then get back a count of the records found. I don't need the lists but I can't get the class to accept anything other than a list for input and output.

There must be a better way!

```
 global class getUnnasociatedCallCount {

       @InvocableMethod
       public static list<string> getRecordCount(List<Id> UserIds) {      
        Integer callcount = [Select Count()
                    FROM Task
                    WHERE Status = 'In Progress'
                    AND WHATID = NULL
                    AND RecordType.Name = 'Five9 Call'
                    AND OwnerID = :UserIds];

        list<string> calllist = new list<string>();
        CallList.add(string.valueof(callcount));
        return callList;
       }
    }
```

Comment: As it is, consider changing `OwnerID = :UserIds` to `OwnerID in :UserIds`.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Any reason why? It compiles either way.

Comment: @sfdcfox True, both work. I'd say using `IN` rather than `=` because it more closely aligns to have the comparison operations are defined. It is clearer that the owner ID is in the collection rather than equals the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a List for both input and output, *because* these methods can be called from different places, and must therefore accept the possibility that they will be used on multiple parameters.

There's a REST API call for them, and you can call them from flows (including Process Builder). By requiring a List, the system enforces the general principle that you should be designing your code to be optimized and bulkified.